# Why does cmd.executeNonQuery() throw ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException?

Tags: c#, oracle, oraclecommand

I tried to write this very simple code to find the problem without any variables, but I can't. If I copy the same query in the sqldeveloper it works.
The ServerVersion still shows up correctly in the messagebox.

The function is called like: `new Dal().testCon();`

```
public OracleConnection con;

public Dal()
{
    con = new OracleConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=satan;Password=666;Data Source=MyDB";
}

public void testCon()
{
    con.Open();
    MessageBox.Show(con.ServerVersion);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into myuser values(1,'Pornstar','xxx',18);", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

[image: Stack-trace]

Comment: If you want someone to help you with an error, you need to post a detailed error message (i.e.  A stack trace, not just the message from the outer exception)

Comment: take out the `;` at the end of your insert statement

Comment: Thank you, didn't even thinked about the semicolon could be a mistake till now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by including the semicolon in the SQL.  Change your query string to `"insert into myuser values(1,'Pornstar','xxx',18)"`.

I'd also recommend moving the connection into the `testCon` method, like so:

```
private const string ConnectionString = "User Id=satan;Password=666;Data Source=MyDB";

public Dal()
{
}

public void testCon()
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into myuser values(1,'Pornstar','xxx',18)", connection);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        MessageBox.Show(connection.ServerVersion);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, I can't believe hours of waste because a semicolon... Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Been there before :-)  Happy to have helped